# Neural network in C

Tags: c, matlab, vector, neural-network

I have a trained neural network for classification problems in Matlab. I want to use the trained weight and apply it in C. My output of the neural network gives me a vector of 7 (`output2[i]`).

How can I use the same vec2ind function in Matlab which takes a matrix of vectors, each containing a single 1, and returns the indices of the ones, and stop as soon as it finds the 1?

I want to implement it in C languages.

I attached part of the code

Thank you

```
double sum = 0;
/// matrix multiplication
for (int i = 0; i < 29; i++)
{
        for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
        {
            sum += inputs[k] * weights[i][k];
        }

        /// apply activation function
        output[i] = tanh_func(sum + biases[i]);
        sum = 0;
}

/// output layer
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 29; k++)
    {
        sum += output[k] * weights2[i][k];
    }

    /// apply activation function
    output2[i] = sigmoid(sum + biases2[i]);
    sum = 0;
}
```

Comment: How about you loop over the array, and stop as soon as you find the 1, and remember the loop index for when that happened?

Comment: Yes. I will edit my question. I want a similar function as vec2ind in Matlab. I want to do it in C. I try to make it but I didn't get the same as the vec2ind function in Matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For writing just vec2ind in C, see other answers.

Alternatively, if you have access to MATLAB Coder, that can convert MATLAB code (the entire algorithm) to C code automatically:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/index.html

Comment: Thank you. vec2ind function is not supported by Matlab coder.

Comment: If calling vec2ind manually, you could replace the call with your own implementation - something as simple as:

<code>
    function [ind, numRows] = my_vec2ind(vec)
        numRows = size(vec, 1);
        numCols = size(vec, 2);
        ind = zeros(1, numCols);
        for col = 1:numCols
            [~, ind(col)] = max(vec(:, col));
        end
    end
</code>

I messed with this comment for a few minutes but triple-backtick for a code block, 4-spaced-indent, and code tags don't seem to work in comments...

Answer (score 0):

To get a better understanding you could use a triple pointer `double*** tensor3d`

initialize it with

```
tensor3d =  malloc( dim0 * sizeof( double** ));
for( int i = 0; i < dim0; ++i )
{
  tensor3d[i] =  malloc( dim1 * sizeof( double* ));
  for( int j = 0; j < dim1; ++j )
  {
    tensor3d[i][j] =  malloc( dim2 * sizeof( double ));
  }
}
```

if you have copied the matrix of vectors inside that 3dim-array you can do that

```
int indices[dim0][dim1];

for( int i = 0; i < dim0; ++i )
{
  for( int j = 0; j < dim1; ++j )
  {
    for( int k = 0; k < dim2; ++k )
    {
      if( tensor3d[i][j][k] > 0.99 && tensor3d[i][j][k] < 1.01 )
      {
        indices[i][j] = k;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but in real life you would use a 1 dim-array `flattensor3d[]` and

```
tensor3d[i][j][k] == flattensor3d[i * dim0 * dim1 + j * dim1 + k]
```